# Webhost claims ASP.NET MVC support, but runs .NET 2.0.50727.4200?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, version, web-hosting

Is a server which returns 2.0.50727.4200 for System.Environment.Version going to support ASP.NET 3.5?

The webhost claims I should ignore the details in the control panel but I get `2.0.50727.4200` when checking the aforementioned system variable.

Comment: The majority of your post was unncessary, and just added a rant to the actual question. Since this is a Q & A site, I edited out the superfluous content so that the question wouldn't be closed a 'Not a real question', or "Subjective and Argumentative."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This article should make things clearer: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/289139.aspx

In short, just because it says it's version 2.0, doesn't mean it isn't actually running 3.5.  v3.0 and v3.5 are essentially updates to v2.0

Answer (score 5):

The CLR for 3.5 is still 2.0, so no, you're not being screwed, it will be fine.

.NET 4.0 will have a 4.0 CLR, so when you're promised .NET 4.0, you can look for a number higher than 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

The runtime for ASP.NET 3.5 is still 2.0

It will be upgraded to 4.0 when .NET 4 is released.

Don't ask my why that is, but ASP.NET MVC will work.

Answer (score 4):

asp.net is version 2.*...
the MVC stuff in 3.+ just extends the base of v2.*...so that is an expected result. as the core of asp.net is still at 2.*... you will be able to run mvc